# How to add numbers i.e. increment before a sentence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, increment, sentence

How do i add numbers before the sentences in python. The code is given below

```
for output in outputs:
    line = tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True,clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    print(line)
```

And the output is :

```
I plan to visit Arsenal against Brighton match on April 9, and are you interested in meeting me at that match?
Hey, I'm planning to visit the game Arsenal vs Brighton on 9th April, are you interested with me in watching this game?
```

I'm trying to get the output like

```
1.) I plan to visit Arsenal against Brighton match on April 9, and are you interested in meeting me at that match?
2.) Hey, I'm planning to visit the game Arsenal vs Brighton on 9th April, are you interested with me in watching this game?
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Question is little confusing. why not use string concatenation? keeping a counter, converting it to string and add it at the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to increment automatically a counter and a f-string:

```
outputs = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3']

for n, output in enumerate(outputs):
    line = output.capitalize() # use your function here
    print(f'{n+1}.) {line}')
```

output:

```
1.) Line1
2.) Line2
3.) Line3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for n_output,output in enumerate(outputs,start=1):
    line = tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    print(n_output, line, sep='.) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use extra variables.
Use index like this :

```
for index,output in outputs:
    line = tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True,clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    print(str(index+1) + '.) ' + line)
```

Output:

```
1.) I plan to visit Arsenal against Brighton match on April 9, and are you interested in meeting me at that match?
2.) Hey, I'm planning to visit the game Arsenal vs Brighton on 9th April, are you interested with me in watching this game?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a variable, increase it on each loop and add the number to the printed text.

```
n = 1
for output in outputs:
    line = f'{str(n).)} {tokenizer.decode(output, skip_special_tokens=True,clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)}'
    n += 1
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration.

```
for i, output in enumerate(outputs, start=1):
    line = output
    print(i, '.)',line)
```